How to migrate a single work item and other items come under that
I would like to migrate a single user story and all the work item comes under this single item.
Eg: One single user story and all its child(Bugs and task)
I am using migration tool and the query I used is
"WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.Id] = 74271 AND [Custom.ReqID] contains 'CR'",


 "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.Id] = 74271 AND [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'",

Both didnt work

You need to be able to craft a query that contains only the things that you want to migrate.
In this case, it would be best to tag the work items that you want, create a list of IDs, or put them in the same area path.
